# Best way to handle permalinked users from my old website to new?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website which contains links like so:

```
http://www.example.com/about
http://www.example.com/about-computing
http://www.example.com/about-web
```

I'm designing a new version of my website which will eventually replace the old.

How can I handle users with these bookmarked to my new website's format?:

```
http://www.example.com/about
http://www.example.com/about/computing
http://www.example.com/about/web
```

Comment: If it is a like for like swap then you shouldn't have an issue, else you will need to either use a .htaccess + PHP file to redirect them

Comment: Well my new system handles URLs in a better way than the old so I'm looking for some sort of server redirection. Htaccess might be the best option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep your old structure and do a manual redirect on each page... But that could get messy very quickly.

Or much cleaner & easier to maintain, you could do it via the .htaccess file

eg:

```
redirect old-URL URL-to-go-to
```

so you could do something like

```
redirect /about-computing http://www.example.com/about/computing
redirect /about-web http://www.example.com/about/web
etc...
```

more information on this [here](http://www.htaccessredirect.co.uk/)

Comment: I wanted it the other way around but this seems to work perfectly for my needs:

    Redirect /about-computing http://www.example.com/about/computing

Comment: In addition, if you wanted to keep the SEO ranking that this page has gained you might consider adding `301` to the rule so the indexer knows this is a permanent move..... `redirect 301 /about-web http://www.example.com/about/web`